# How to get the eq() value?

Tags: jquery

Is this possible? For me to get the `eq()` value? For example, if I click the `li:eq(2)`, var `x` will become `2`. Here's the code.

```
$('#numbers ul li').click(function(){
  x=$(this).eq().val();
  alert(x);
});
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `.index()`<sup>[what is this?](http://api.jquery.com/index/)</sup> method will do it.

```
$('#numbers ul li').click(function() {
  var self   = $(this),
      index  = self.index(),
      text   = self.text();

  alert(text + ' ' + index);
});
```

**Demo**: http://www.jsfiddle.net/Y2aDP/

Comment: Index is not equavalent when you have more than 1 list.

Comment: Strictly speaking, index() is not the same as eq(). index() gives you back the actual index of the element, while using the eq() selector manipulates the indexes to filter for the type of element you're searching for. Checkout this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vND37/) for an example.

Comment: While `$(this).index()` gives you the order of element in parent, `$(".yourclass").index(this)` gives you the order of your class in parent.

Answer (score 6):

The answer above is wrong. Index provides a relative value with respect to its siblings. Hence, the value is expected to change.

It should be something like

```
$('.someClass').click(function(){
    var that_ = this;
    // your logic for this function
    ....
    ....
    var currentIndex = $('.someClass').index(_that);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`eq<>` index:

```
scount=$(selector).length;
for(i=0; i<scount; i++){
    $("selector:eq("+i+")").attr("eq",i);
}
$("selector").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("eq"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one..

```
 $('#numbers ul li').click(function(){
   var x=$(this).index();
   alert(x);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You must give a context to `index()` in order to have an equivalent of `eq()`. Otherwise `index()` returns a relative value.

```
 $('#numbers ul li').click(function(){
   var x=$(this).index('#numbers ul li');
   alert(x);
 });
```