# jquery alert .eq() value

Tags: jquery, function, indexing

I kind of understand how .eq() function works in jquery,

```
<ul>
<li>item 2</li>
<li>item 4</li>
<li>item adf</li>
<li>item f</li>
</ul>

$('ul').find('li').eq(3); //this gives item f
```

but what if I wanted to click on item adf, how do I get an alert of 2.

```
$('ul li').click(function(){
alert('//getting eq value'); //and then when clicked, it should say 2
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for the [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method:

```
alert($(this).index());
```

From the docs:

> If no argument is passed to the `.index()` method, the return value is
>   an integer indicating the position of the first element within the
>   jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.

Comment: Was going to do some magic with prevUntil but you beat me to it with a nicer solution : )

Comment: @AlexanderVarwijk - That's one of the great things about jQuery - there's often a nice simple solution!

Answer (score 0):

To get the index of the clicked element, you can use `this` as the selector to select the clicked element, and then the index() method to get the index of the element:

```
$("ul li").click(function(){
   alert($(this).index());
});
```

Comment: @Adam The question has been edited, when I wrote the answer there were neither quotation-marks nor apostrophes surrounding the selector.

Comment: Oh okay, I thought there was something I didn't know about for a second, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions will not work when the list is long.
index() returns relative value and the value will change when more list tags are added.

you should perhaps, do something as follows -

```
$('ul li').click(function(){
     var currentListIndex = $('ul li').index(this);
     alert(currentListIndex);
});
```

Comment: @andrewliu **Also, this is a redundant question. Please find the answers here** - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849677/how-to-get-the-eq-value/24141707#24141707